# run a function when an Ember.Object is created

Tags: ember.js

I need to run a function when a particular object is created to validate the environment is setup correctly.

This works on an Ember.Controller but not on an Ember.Object.

```
checkEnvironment : function() {

    ...

}.on('init'),
```

Is there a way to hook into the contructor somehow?

Comment: on init should work. Have a look at this http://emberjs.jsbin.com/parace/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions don't really have an `on` method, perhaps you are confusing them with [observers](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/observers/)?

```
fullNameChanged: function() {
   // deal with the change
}.observes('fullName').on('init')
```

What you can do, is override the `init` methid, and call `this._super()`

```
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.checkEnvironment();
  },
```